# Send HTTP response that doesn't change the user's current page

Tags: python, flask, httpresponse, wsgi

I have a JavaScript bookmarklet that POSTs information to a (Flask powered) server while the user is on some other page (i.e. not one on my server).  I don't want to interrupt the user's browsing by hijacking their session with my server response.

My initial thought was that I could suppress the HTTP response from Flask somehow; prevent it from sending anything to the client so they aren't mysteriously redirected.  I was hoping I could do this by perhaps having a null return from a view.

I then thought that might be some HTTP response that lets the client know the information was successfully submitted, but will leave the client on their current page.  Suppose a header value like "Here is the result of your request, but you should not alter your current display"?

Comment: your client will be waiting in vain, why would you do that?

Comment: If you somehow forced Flask to do this the browser would eventually time out when it got tired of waiting for a response

Comment: @nzjk2 - this is an interim solution.  I am using a Javascript bookmarklet to get information to the server.  At that point the "client" browser is on a page that I do not control.  Not my page, and I don't want to interrupt the user's browsing by hijacking his session.  Later, I expect to encapsulate this operation in a plug-in.

Comment: IanAuld - See my response to nzjk2 above.  I am looking for a means of sending data via http to a server without expecting a response from the server.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I have recently seen suggestions for editing my question.  I disapprove of the proposed changes because they remove the specific circumstances of my original question - the interactions between HTTP communications and Flask.  I recognize that the accepted answer does not depend on Flask, but my use of Flask was instrumental in bringing out the issue.  The answer is excellent and is applicable in a larger community, but the question belongs in the Flask community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your amended question, yes there is such a response.  From [RFC 2616-section 10](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) (emphasis added):

> **10.2.5 204 No Content**
>
> The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an
>   entity-body, and might want to return updated metainformation. The
>   response MAY include new or updated metainformation in the form of
>   entity-headers, which if present SHOULD be associated with the
>   requested variant.
>
> If the client is a user agent, it **SHOULD NOT change its document view
>   from that which caused the request to be sent**. This response is
>   primarily intended to allow input for actions to take place without
>   causing a change to the user agent's active document view, although
>   any new or updated metainformation SHOULD be applied to the document
>   currently in the user agent's active view.
>
> The 204 response *MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always
>   terminated by the first empty line after the header fields.*

Thus from flask you can do something like this. Remember, the response must not include a message body, so any data you want to send back should be put into a cookie.

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    r = flask.Response()
    r.set_cookie("My important cookie", value=some_cool_value)
    return r, 204
```

Comment: Dannnno - This is what I was looking for. After reading your answer, it is clear that I should have gone to the RFC-2616 docs after recasting my question.  This resolves my issues with HTTP and with Flask.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible.  Flask is built on Werkzeug, which implements the WSGI spec.  The WSGI cycle requires sending a response to each request.  Droping the response would require control over the TCP/IP connection at a far lower level even that HTTP. This is outside the domain of WSGI, therefore outside the domain of Flask.

You could return an error code, or an empty body, but you have to return *something*.

```
return ''  # empty body
```